# Make images resize depending on device

Tags: html, css, image, resize, image-resizing

I am trying to make a website using MDL and I want to use cards to list the different places on the website people can go.

I can't get the images to resize to different devices.

I am currently writing it on a tablet (surface pro 3) and thought it was working okay till I tested it on my phone and my desktop and I realised it wasn't scaling.

My code is in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7r0cqz6/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.teal-pink.min.css"/>
        <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <title>Man of Steelbook</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Wide card with share menu button -->
        <style>
        .demo-card.mdl-card {
          width: 98%;
        }
        .demo-card > .mdl-card__title {
          color: #fff;
          max-width: 100%;
          height: auto;
        }
        .demo-card > .mdl-card__menu {
          color: #fff;
        }
        </style>

        <!-- Simple header with scrollable tabs. -->
        <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
          <header class="mdl-layout__header">
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
              <!-- Title -->
              <span class="mdl-layout-title">Man of Steelbook</span>
            </div>
          </header>

          <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
             <span class="mdl-layout-title" style="background-color: teal; color: white; border: 0px;">Man of Steelbook</span>
                <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                  <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                  <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="about.html">About Me</a>
                  <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="my_collection.html">My Collection</a>
                  <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </nav>
          </div>
          <main class="mdl-layout__content">
          <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="scroll-tab-3">
              <div class="page-content">
                <div class="mdl-grid">
                  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
                    <div class="demo-card mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
                      <div class="mdl-card__title" style="background: url('imgs/marvel.jpg') center / cover;">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                        Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
                      </div>
                      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                          Get Started
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
                    <div class="demo-card mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
                      <div class="mdl-card__title" style="background: url('imgs/DC.png') center / cover;">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                        Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
                      </div>
                      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                          Get Started
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
                    <div class="demo-card mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
                      <div class="mdl-card__title" style="background: url('imgs/dis_pix.jpg') center / cover;">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                        Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
                      </div>
                      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                          Get Started
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
            </main>
        </div>
</html>
```

I'm not used to asking questions on here so if i've missed any information or you need anything else then just ask and ill provide it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting the full image to be displayed on all resolutions/screen sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the whole banner image to display on top of each card. If so, the images themselves need to be the same aspect ratio (otherwise the cards will be different heights), then divide the height of the image by the width to get the aspect ratio represented as a percentage, then set that percentage as `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` of the element they're applied to. Also ensure that the element has 0 height, or no height specified and no content inside it.

Here is your current layout with the aspect ratio of each image as padding for each card. Since the images are different sizes, the cards will be different heights.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.teal-pink.min.css"/>
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <title>Man of Steelbook</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- Wide card with share menu button -->
  <style>
  .demo-card.mdl-card {
    width: 98%;
  }
  .demo-card > .mdl-card__title {
    color: #fff;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
      padding: 0;
  }
  .demo-card > .mdl-card__menu {
    color: #fff;
  }
  </style>
 
  <!-- Simple header with scrollable tabs. -->
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
   <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
     <!-- Title -->
     <span class="mdl-layout-title">Man of Steelbook</span>
   </div>
    </header>
    
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title" style="background-color: teal; color: white; border: 0px;">Man of Steelbook</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="about.html">About Me</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="my_collection.html">My Collection</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="scroll-tab-3">
     <div class="page-content">
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
     <div class="demo-card mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
       <div class="mdl-card__title" style="background: url('http://djgb.co.uk/imgs/marvel.jpg') center / cover;padding-top:50%;">
       </div>
       <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
       </div>
       <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
      <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        Get Started
      </a>
       </div>
     </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
     <div class="demo-card mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
       <div class="mdl-card__title" style="background: url('http://djgb.co.uk/imgs/DC.png') center / cover;padding-top: 37.015%">
       </div>
       <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
       </div>
       <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
      <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        Get Started
      </a>
       </div>
     </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
     <div class="demo-card mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
       <div class="mdl-card__title" style="background: url('http://djgb.co.uk/imgs/dis_pix.jpg') center / cover;padding-top: 25.4%">
       </div>
       <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
       </div>
       <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
      <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        Get Started
      </a>
       </div>
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     </div>
   </section>
   </main>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is sorted my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think for the class `mdl-card__title` you need to set the `background-size` to something like `contain`.

See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/ for more information.

Comment: Doing that makes the image repeat at a very small size?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
#portal-logo img {
    width: 33%;
    max-width: 180px; 
    height: auto;
}
```

For more information click [Here](https://opensourcehacker.com/2012/01/09/styling-images-for-mobile-with-css-width-and-max-width-mobilizing-websites-with-responsive-design-and-html5-part-6/)

Comment: What will this affect? OP doesn't have any `img`s in their code?

Comment: Your css with doesn't have any effect as the outer element doesn't have a width defined (and body is missing as well).

A different approach is to deliver already scaled images. http://www.sencha.com/products/io/ for example delivers the image already scaled down depending on the viewing device.